# Nested form attributes wont save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am required to use nested forms on an assignment I am working on and I got stuck because my nested form attributes wont submit to database.

Here is what my controller looks like

```
def new
  @booking = Booking.new
  params[:no_of_passengers].to_i.times { @booking.passengers.build }
end

def create
  @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @booking.save  
      format.html { redirect_to '/booking_confirmed', notice: 'Booking was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @booking }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @booking.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end



private

def booking_params
  params.permit(
    :airline, :origin, :destination, :departure_date, :departure_time, :arrival_date,
    :arrival_time, :flight_id, :price, :no_of_passengers, :user_id, :booking,
    passenger_attributes: [
      :id,:booking_id, :name, :email,:done,:_destroy
    ]
  )
end
```

Here is the association between the models

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :passengers

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :passengers, reject_if: lambda { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank? }
end


class Passenger < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bookings
end
```

And here is the form

```
<%= form_for @booking do |b| %>
  <%= b.fields_for :passengers do |p| %>
     <%= p.text_field :name, placeholder: "Passenger Name" %>
     <%= p.text_field :email, placeholder: "Passenger Email"  %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I checked the passenger table using `Passenger.all` in rails console and it returns nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the sent params you get from your form?

Comment: please show what are the values of `params` and `booking_params` when the request is submitted.

Comment: `Started POST "/bookings" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-08 14:00:49 +0100
Processing by BookingsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"S95Splfs70P954xJ/AN8t9k8E8OBvwCRdwrx5nSSwziLo/GFF4I102/cbB3ZUDToz/oofuwZCQIr9tEmsZ+W4w==", "booking"=>{"flight_id"=>"608", "user_id"=>"", "no_of_passengers"=>"", "passengers_attributes"=>{"1446987645041"=>{"name"=>"ade", "email"=>"ade", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Book Now"}
Unpermitted parameter: passengers_attributes
`

Comment: please ignore the email in the params, it was left that way for testing purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a pairing session with [sunnyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4330954/sunnyk), I was able to see the errors.

The first error was that my `class Passenger` has `belongs_to :bookings` instead of `belongs_to :booking`. This is a common error though. The Associations between these classes now looks like:

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :flight
  has_many :passengers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :passengers, reject_if: 
  lambda {|attributes| attributes['name'].blank?}, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Passenger < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :booking
end

class Flight < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :passengers, through: :bookings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :passengers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bookings
end
```

Next:
Instead of using the default value of `no_of_passengers` for building my nested form, I used the [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) gem, which makes nested forms building and management easier. I also crated a new `params` method, in which I made the `flight_id` permitted, and then passed it as an argument for my booking instance in my `new` method alongside my `current user`. So now my `new` method looks like this.

```
def new
  @booking = Booking.new(new_booking_params)
  @booking.user = current_user if current_user
end

def new_booking_params
  params.permit(:flight_id)
end
```

After that, I had to make another `params` method for my `create` method, so as to allow the parameters I want in the `bookings` table, this include the `passengers_attributes`. Now my `create` method looks like this.

```
 def create
  @booking = Booking.new(another_booking_params)
  respond_to do |format|
   if @booking.save  
    format.html { redirect_to '/booking_confirmed', notice: 'Booking was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @booking }
   else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @booking.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end
end

 def another_booking_params
  params.require(:booking).permit(:flight_id, :user_id, :no_of_passengers,  
  passengers_attributes:[:name, :email])
 end
```

Lastly, I had to adjust my form to look like this.

```
<%= form_for(@booking, url: bookings_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field(:flight_id)%>
  <%= f.hidden_field(:user_id) %>
  <%= f.hidden_field(:no_of_passengers)%>
  <%= f.fields_for :passengers do |passenger| %>
    <%= render 'passenger_fields', :f => passenger %>
    <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Another passenger',f, :passengers, :class => 'btn btn-primary add' %> 
  <%= submit_tag "Book Now", class: "btn btn-primary book" %>
<% end %>
```

and `passenger_fields` partial looks like.

```
<div class="nested-fields form-inline">
 <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :name, :class => "form-control", placeholder: "Passenger Name" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>-</label>
    <%= f.text_field :email, :class => "form-control", placeholder: "Passenger Email"  %>
  </div>
  <div class="links pull-right">
    <%= link_to_remove_association "Delete", f, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
```

All that did the trick. I hope this will help others to understand nested forms better